# Как сделать таймеры для разных комнат node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Как сделать таймеры для разных комнат node.js? Ка лучше или как правильно сделать таймеры для разных столов?
Пытаюсь так, но у то кого способа нет возможности удалить таймер.

```
let room={};
function getTimer (e){
    room[e]={
        time:(function () {
            let i=10;
            function time() {
                i--;
                console.log("тик так",i);
                if(i>0){
                    setTimeout(time,1000)
                }
                if(i===0){
                    //что то произошло
                }
            }
            time();

        })(),
        use:{}
    };
}
getTimer(1)
getTimer(2)
```

Как правильно реализовать таймер на каждую комнату с возможностью отключения или удаления его? Например в тот момент если люди покинули комнату за которым данный таймер ведет отсчет?

Comment: Что такое **стол**?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko Извиняюсь не правильно выразился. Стол я имел введу комната. Поправил вопрос

Comment: Немного лучше. Теперь, что такое **комната**?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko Например комната 1 с чатом общение в этой комнате видят пользователи которые находятся только в ней так же как и в комнате 2. Что называться в сокетах пространства. То есть  сообщения видят только те кто находятся в ней, а не все пользователи чата(подключенные к сокету). Вот и таймер надо сделать такой-же

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать в стиле ООП.

```js
class MyTimer {
  isRunning = false;
  timeoutId;
  name;
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
  start() {
    this.isRunning = true;
    let i = 10;

    var time = () => {
      if (!this.isRunning) {
        this.stop();
        return;
      }
      i--;
      console.log(this.name, "тик так", i);
      if (i > 0) {
        this.timeoutId = setTimeout(time, 1000);
      }
      if (i === 0) {
        this.stop();
        //что то произошло
      }
    }
    time();
  }
  stop() {
    clearTimeout(this.timeoutId);
    this.isRunning = false;
  }
}
var timer1 = new MyTimer('первый');
var timer2 = new MyTimer('второй');
timer1.start();
// Останавливаем первый таймер через 3 секунды
setTimeout(function() {
  timer1.stop();
}, 3000);
timer2.start();
```